# I coudlnt catch ctrl+space key event in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, keyeventargs

I couldnt catch ctrl+space key event in winForm.But i wrote this code `((e.KeyCode==Keys.Space)&&(e.Modifiers==Keys.Control))` it didnt work.What is the problem?

[EDIT]sorry.problem is in another thing.It works.

Comment: Which event of which control are you attaching to?
Are you getting invoked for other keystrokes at all?

Comment: PreviewKeyDown event of textBox,it raise event,but i cannot catch ctrl+space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `(e.Modifiers & Keys.Control == Keys.Control)` instead of `(e.Modifiers==Keys.Control)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

```
if (e.KeyData.HasFlag(Keys.Space) && e.KeyData.HasFlag(Keys.Control))
{
    // DoSomething
}
```